# Yii Bootstrap extension. Pagination

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

How to configure my widget that he showed the number of results displayed on the screen? Such as in standard CGridview pagination (Showing 1 - 10 of 4087 for *****)

```
 <?php $this->widget('common.ext.bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'search-by-name-grid',
    'type' => 'striped',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>'{items}{pager}',
    'enablePagination' => true,
    'columns'=>array(
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to specify `{summary}` in the `template` attribute

```
<?php $this->widget('common.ext.bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'search-by-name-grid',
    'type' => 'striped',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>'{summary}{items}{pager}',
    'enablePagination' => true,
    'columns'=>array(
```

**FOR CONFIGURING THE FORMAT OF THE SUMMARY TEXT**

`TbGridView` is extended from [`CGridView`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView). So you can use the [`summaryText`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseListView#summaryText-detail) attribute of `CGridView`

```
<?php $this->widget('common.ext.bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'id'=>'search-by-name-grid',
    'type' => 'striped',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'template'=>'{summary}{items}{pager}',
    'enablePagination' => true,
    'summaryText'=>'Displaying {start}-{end} of {count} results.'
```

According to the documentation you can use the following tokens in `summaryText'

> ```
> {start}: the starting row number (1-based) currently being displayed
> {end}: the ending row number (1-based) currently being displayed
> {count}: the total number of rows
> {page}: the page number (1-based) current being displayed, available since version 1.1.3
> {pages}: the total number of pages, available since version 1.1.3
> ```